# How to resize,rotate image in android over other image or view through touch

Tags: android, imageview, gestures

I am working on a application which has an background image let say ImageOcean(image1) and then I want to put another image on it let say ImageShark(image2) so I want to put shark on the spot where user has put the shark over the ocean using touch. Not only he would put the shark but I want also zoom in and zoom out. I saw [this](https://github.com/judepereira/android-multitouch) link and it has only zoom in/out, movement but no rotations. I need rotation too.

I have nothing to share because I just starting it and I have no idea how to accomplish it. Please share me a link of any tutorial or source code.

> **EDIT**

I found the rotation in it. Now my question is How can I get the values of X,Y and there size after getting zoom

Comment: your link supports rotation also

Comment: OK new update great..

Answer (score 1):

Rotate with multitouch is not easy in Android, lots of code have to be written in order to make it work nicely. I suggest you to use an existing library.[HERE](https://github.com/lukehutch/android-multitouch-controller)

Comment: is it free and legal to use.

Comment: @can you please elaborate how can I use it I mean there are three folders in it , which one is to download (I have never used github codes before)

Comment: below those 3 maps there is info about every one of them. Look up for :  README.md. And if you don't know how to use github then just google it "how to use github"

Comment: I do not know how to use it . Not even how to use it  directly on ImageView

Answer (score 0):

I think `ViewDragHelper` would help. check [this](http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/08/28/each-navigation-drawer-hides-a-viewdraghelper/).